# Makefile foreach

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to create a makefile which downloads some pre-requisite files to a path.

But the [foreach documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html) is sadly lacking in detail and examples.

I want something like:

```
image_files = a b
image_versions = 701.2 802.1
image_path = images
images = $(foreach ...) ??
```

I'd like that to result in an expansion to:

```
images/701.2/a
images/701.2/b
images/802.1/a
images/802.1/b
```

And have a phony target to download them from a URL like:

```
mytarget: $(images)
wget somepath $<
```

How do I do that?

---

Ok I have gotten a little further with this.  But I'm still a little perplexed as to how I can get this to work.

```
tag = my-registry:8443/boot-server-data
versions = 557.0.0 607.0.0

images_a = $(foreach ver, $(versions), images/$(ver)/coreos_production_pxe_image.cpio.gz)
images_b = $(foreach ver, $(versions), images/$(ver)/coreos_production_pxe.vmlinuz)

all: build
.PHONY: build $(images_a) $(images_b)

build:
        ./make-profiles
        docker build -t $(tag) .
        docker push $(tag) 

$(images_a): 
        wget http://stable.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/$(foreach version... but depends on each image)/coreos_production
```

How do you do this?

In fact I only want it to download the images if they aren't there.  But for some reason it downloads it every time.  It's literally been years since I used Make.  I normally use another build tool, but that build tool needs to be modified to make it do what I want here.  So I thought I'd just whip this up in the meantime.  It's prooving to be a little harder than expected.

Comment: There is an example which shows how it works in the manual. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I need 2 sets of foreach.

Comment: ok, I now understand the first parameter is a variable which can be substituted into the 3rd.  That wasn't immediately clear.

Comment: Yes, you will need two nested calls to foreach for this.

Comment: Edited my answer... a little stuck on making that work nicely.

Comment: How does the URL in that wget correspond to the `images/.../coreos...` file of the current target?

Comment: well, for example http://stable.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/607.0.0/coreos_production_pxe.vmlinuz

Comment: make will attempt to create a file whenever it is referenced if it doesn't exist. If your wget isn't generating **exactly** the target name then as far as make is concerned it doesn't exist. The corollary is that if you need make to be smart and download the file when it has changed remotely that gets complicated.

Comment: So the URL uses the bit *after* `images/` in the file/target name? Try `$(patsubst images/%,%,$@)` in the URL.

Comment: You seem to have worked out the answer to your original question (how to use `foreach` to construct the list). If you now want to know how to use Make to do something with a remote file system, you should ask a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close, but the problem does not lie with `foreach`. Let's have a look at just the bit that does the downloading. When *make* reads the makefile it ends up with something like (after shortening the names a bit for clarity):

```
images/1/file.cpio.gz images/2/file.cpio.gz:
    <recipe>
```

If, for some reason, *make* decides to rebuild `images/1/file.cpio.gz` say, at this point it will expand the recipe, and pass each line of that expansion to a separate shell.

Your job is to write a recipe that does not care whether the target is `images/1/file.cpio.gz` or `images/2/file.cpio.gz`. That's another  way of saying the recipe should use macros like `$@` (it will expand to the target).

A sketch:

```
${images_a}:
    wget -O $@ http://stable.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/$@
```

You may have to munge `$@` so that *wget* gets the right url. Just one example:

```
${images_a}:
    wget -O $@ http://stable.release.core-os.net/$(dirname $@)/deeper/$(notdir $@)
```

One complaint about your original makefile: the dependencies are wrong. `build` needs the downloads to have completed before it runs.

```
.PHONY: build

build: $(images_a) $(images_b)
    ...
```

The images are not phony (just ensure you don't lie to *make* abut their filenames) either.

The massive advantage of writing your makefile in this way is that it's parallel safe (and that's the *whole* point of *make*). When `-j` is in force, both wgets can proceed *at the same time*, halving the download time.